# find the dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

E and F are 2 linear spaces 
G is a linear subspace of E 
1) show that g={u in L(E) / G is included in  ker u} is a linear subspace of L(E,F) 
2) calculate the dimension of g in function of dimE , dimF and dimG

1) its easy to show that  u= OE in g (G is included ker(0) =E)
also for u,v in g 
a in IK 
a.u +v in g
2) let us suppose that H is the supplementary of G in E 
H + G = E 
we must define u in L(E) in each of H and G 
using the restiction of u in G

u/G : G in E 
          x associates u(x)
using the restriction of u in H 
u/H : H in E
          x associates u(x)

then g= {u in L(E)  that u/G =0E and u/H in L(h,E) }
let K from g to **what it the target set** L(H,E) or L(H,F)
         that u associates u/H 
   we show that K is an isomorphism

then dim(g) = dim(starting space of K )* dim (target set of K)

Comment: Your post is unreadable, however, your work seems to be on the right track. What is your exact question?

Comment: what is the target set of K

Comment: and I don't know how to edit my post

Comment: To edit your post, click where it says [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3299540/edit) above

Comment: I don't know how to edit it mathematically

Comment: For one thing, your post would be more readable if you started sentences with capital letters and put periods at the end of sentences.   [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial for formatting mathematical expressions

Comment: thank you I will do it properly next time